# Alphabetical Sorting with <input>

Tags: javascript, sorting, input, alphabetical-sort

i would like to have a sorting routine for 5 words to sort alphabetical (From A-Z and Z-A), what I came up with (with help from some sites) was this. (excuses, I couldn't post a screen capture due not enough rep)

Script:

```
Function Sorter(){

var routine=["Banana","Milkshake","Work","bladiebla","Progress"];

routine.sort();

(routine.reverse();) if possible

var x=document.GetElementById("demo");

x.innerHTML=routine;}
```

this works, and is set in work by a button (not in this code). however what i want is that i can fill in the words myself on my site. i have used prompt tags and input tags but they dont seem to work (when i do it).
could anyone please help me out with this.

what i would like: i would like to be able to use prompt tags (or input tags) to put the words in the array and then sort the words alphabetically A-Z and backwards Z-A.
if someone would want to help me out with this then i would like that,

thanks in advance, Dim

Comment: If you need a screencap, you can link to it and someone will add it to the post.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to add the value entered in input box into an array and list the values in asc/desc order. I have created the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pHqRX/3/) it might be helpful.

```
$('input').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && $.trim(this.value)) {
        routine.push(this.value);
        Sorter();
        this.value = '';
    }
});
var routine=["Banana","Milkshake","Work","bladiebla","Progress"];
function Sorter() {
    routine.sort();
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML = routine.join('<br>');
}
Sorter();
```